# Is ImmutableMap a sub-optimal choice for large volume of keys/objects/

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, guava

I was doing some tests with a colleague, and we were pulling data in from a database (about 350,000 records), converting each record into an object and a key object, and then populating them into an ImmutableMap.Builder.

When we called the build() method it took forever, probably due to all the data integrity checks that come with ImmutableMap (dupe keys, nulls, etc). To be fair we tried to use a hashmap as well, and that took awhile but not as long as the ImmutableMap. We finally settled on just using ConcurrentHashMap which we populated with 9 threads as the records were iterated, and wrapped that in an unmodifiable map. The performance was good.

I noticed on the documentation it read ImutableMap is not optimized for "equals()" operations. As a die-hard immutable-ist, I'd like the ImmutableMap to work for large data volumes but I'm getting the sense it is not meant for that. Is that assumption right? Is it optimized only for small/medium-sized data sets? Is there a hidden implementation I need to invoke via  "copyOf()" or something?

Comment: Is this to create a cache?

Comment: No not really. I need to do massive amounts of lookups using a key containing a dozen properties, and comparing hundreds of thousands of objects against another set of hundreds of thousands of objects to see what is exclusive to each set. Kind of like a SQL outer join but not as simple...

Comment: Dupe keys and null checking fall out almost for free from how hash-based collections have to be constructed in any event.  This result surprises me.  (Also, `ImmutableMap` should take somewhat less memory than `HashMap`.)

Comment: I'll need to go back and time the two. Maybe my qualitative assessment was wrong. But yeah both the hashmap and immutable map were taking forever to construct. Or perhaps I need to optimize my hashcoding, although I can't think of much to optimize it. Let me do some more controlled tests and ill get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that none of Java's built in `Collection` classes are really optimised for performance at huge volumes. For example HashMap uses simple iteration once hashCode has been used as an index in the array and compares the key via `equals` to each item with the same hash. If you are going to store several million items in the map then you need a very well designed hash and large capacity. These classes are designed to be as generic and safe as possible.

So performance optimisations to try if you wish to stick with the standard Java HashMap:

1. Make sure your hash function provides as close as possible to even distribution. Many domains have skewed values and your hash needs to take account of this.
2. When you have a lot of data `HashMap` will be expanded many times. Ideally set initial capacity as close as possible to the final value.
3. Make sure your `equals` implementation is as efficient as possible.

There are massive performance optimisations you can apply if you know (for example) that your key is an integer, for example using some form of btree after the hash has been applied and using `==` rather than `equals`.

So the simple answer is that I believe you will need to write your own collection to get the performance you want or use one of the more optimised implementations available.

Comment: Ergh, I dont know if I want to go that far and start writing my own Map implementations. I may research that anyway just to learn about the optimizations you speak of.

Comment: Ok I'll add a couple of tips to my answer on how to improve performance of the supplied implementations.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Do IDE's like Eclipse follow optimizations 1 and 2 somewhat? I'm assuming they do because the prime 31 is the standard, and the equals is always seeking a false condition before returning true. When I have Eclipse build the code for me, this is typically what it does.

Comment: Yes the modern IDEs are pretty good in their code generation. But they can't replace knowledge of the data domain: only you will know how the data might be skewed.

Comment: Absolutely, I always review and tweak when needed since Eclipse may not understand the classes it is hashcoding.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your `key.equals()` is a time consuming method.

`key.equals()` will be called **much more times** in `ImmutableMap.build()` than `HashMap.put()` (in a loop). And `key.hashCode()` is called **same times**, both `HashMap.put()` and `ImmutableMap.build()`. As result, if `key.equals()` takes long time, the whole duration can be different much.

`key.equals()` are called a few times during `HashMap.put()` (Good hash algorithm leads a few collision).
While in case of `ImmutableMap.build()`,  `key.equals()` will be called many times when `checkNoConflictInBucket()`. O(n) for `key.equals()`.

Once the map is built, two types of Map should not be different much when access, as both are hash-based.

Sample: 
There are 10000 random String to put as keys. `HashMap.put()` calls
 `String.equals()` 2 times, while `ImmutableMap.build()` calls 3000 times.

Comment: This is really helpful, I was somewhat suspecting a behavior like this was going on. But its good to know that post-build(), reading the map is pretty much the same. Thanks.